# How to open pdf file from android code directly

Tags: android, pdf

I am working on an android project where I have to show a pdf through our project. The pdf is located at some URL (e.g http://www.cbwe.gov.in/HTMLEditor1/pdf/sample.pdf ).

I have to  directly open the pdf without saving it on the phone using android code like browser. In android we can not show pdf in browser.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Google docs viewer http://docs.google.com/viewer?pli=1. This is a complete in browser solution for viewing PDFs and it should work on mobile phones. Be aware that this solution converts pdf's to images and might turn out very data intensive (in other words expensive for users without flat rate data plans).